# Parallelstream.ForEach() double item

Tags: java, asynchronous, parallel.foreach

I have a piece of software that generates SOAP-requests based on an excel-file, and then emails the results.

Due to the potential size of the requests, I do the soap-request-handling in parallel. The following code handles the above mentioned.

```
    public void HandleData() {
    List<NodeAnalysisReply> replies = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
    new Thread(() -> {
        List<NodeAnalysisRequest> requests;
        SOAPMessageFactory factory = new SOAPMessageFactory();
        SOAPResponseParser parser = new SOAPResponseParser();

        try {
            requests = new ExcelParser().parseData(file);
            requests.parallelStream().forEach((request) -> {
                try {
                    SOAPMessage message = factory.createNodeRequestMessage(
                            new RequestObject(requestInfoFactory.makeInfo(trackingID), request));
                    SOAPMessage response = new SoapConnector(server.getUrl()).executeRequest(message);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    response.writeTo(out);
                    NodeAnalysisReply curReply = parser.ParseXMLResponse(out.toString(), request);
                    synchronized (replies) {
                        System.out.println("Adding: " + curReply.getRequest().toString());
                        replies.add(curReply);
                    }
                } catch (UnsupportedOperationException | SOAPException | IOException e) {
                    handleSoap(e.getMessage());
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            handleBadParse();
        }

        try {
            for(NodeAnalysisReply reply : replies){
                System.out.println("Data: " + reply.getRequest().toString());
            }
            mailer.SendEmail("Done", email, replies);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }).start();
}
```

When I run the code with two piece of data, the following happens:

```
Adding: Søndergade 52 6920 // OK
Adding: Ternevej 1 6920 // OK

Data: Ternevej 1 6920 // What
Data: Ternevej 1 6920 // WHAT..
are equal? true
```

So even though it adds both items to the list, it seems like the last one takes both places. How come is that, and how do I solve it? - I really do miss the Parrallel.ForEach() form C#!

EDIT: As requested, the code for NodeAnalysisReply.

```
public class NodeAnalysisReply {

 public ReplyInfo getReplyInfo() {
  return replyInfo;
 }

 public void setReplyInfo(ReplyInfo replyInfo) {
  this.replyInfo = replyInfo;
 }

 public List < nodeAnalysisListDetails > getNodeAnalysisListDetails() {
  return nodeAnalysisListDetails;
 }

 public void setNodeAnalysisListDetails(List < nodeAnalysisListDetails > nodeAnalysisListDetails) {
  this.nodeAnalysisListDetails = nodeAnalysisListDetails;
 }

 public void addNodeAnalysisListDetail(nodeAnalysisListDetails nodeAnalysisListDetails) {
  this.nodeAnalysisListDetails.add(nodeAnalysisListDetails);
 }
 ReplyInfo replyInfo;
 public String getFormattedXML() {
  return formattedXML;
 }

 public void setFormattedXML(String formattedXML) {
  this.formattedXML = formattedXML;
 }
 String formattedXML;
 public NodeAnalysisRequest getRequest() {
  return request;
 }

 public void setRequest(NodeAnalysisRequest request) {
  this.request = request;
 }
 NodeAnalysisRequest request;

 List < nodeAnalysisListDetails > nodeAnalysisListDetails = new ArrayList < > ();

}
```

Comment: Show us the code of NodeAnalysisReply

Comment: @JBNizet added to OP.

Comment: I was suspecting the request field to be static. It's not. My next suspicion is that parser.ParseXMLResponse always returns the same object. Show us the code of the parser

Comment: It doesn't else this output when adding would be the same too.

Comment: No, they wouldn't. the first print would show the unique object with the state it has after the first parse, and the second print would show it with the state it has after the second parse.

Comment: @JBNizet you are right! The problem is as you thought. It keeps the previous state, and therefore returns the same item. Thank you so much for that observation!

Answer (score 0):

```
synchronized (replies) {
     System.out.println("Adding: " + curReply.getRequest().toString());
     replies.add(curReply);
}
```

The above code in a lambda of stream is called a side effect and is not encouraged at all.

What you should do is something like below.

```
replies.addAll(requests.parallelStream().map((request) -> {
                try {
                    SOAPMessage message = factory.createNodeRequestMessage(
                            new RequestObject(requestInfoFactory.makeInfo(trackingID), request));
                    SOAPMessage response = new SoapConnector(server.getUrl()).executeRequest(message);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    response.writeTo(out);
                    NodeAnalysisReply curReply = parser.ParseXMLResponse(out.toString(), request);
                    return curReply;
                } catch (UnsupportedOperationException | SOAPException | IOException e) {
                    handleSoap(e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                }
            })
            .filter(curReply -> curReply != null)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
        );
```

In the Above code you map each `request` to a `NodeAnalysisReply` first and then filter only the non null values and finally you Collect it into a list and all those to your `replies` list.

Comment: I agree with all this, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. Though it doesn't change, that the two object in "replies" are still equal.

Comment: @BenjaminLarsen it looks like a Race Condition for me. Please check the synchronization policy of `replies`